# XirSys $.ajax() method returned status 400, error: Could not validate application

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, turn

I'm developing my own webRTC app following Sam Dutton tutorials, I am using xirSys to provide TURN server for my peer-to-peer video. BUT `$.ajax()` method doesn't return the credential, username, url as I expect. I also tried to use `dataType: JSONP`.
The response returned returned when debugging from firebug is:

> {"p":"/getIceServers","s":400,"d":null,"e":"Could not validate application"}

Is there anyway that I could get my **url**, **username**, **credential** as **JSON** and use them directly in my app without getting any error because even if the status of a url hit is 200 there is still a syntax error sometimes when `$.ajax()` is called?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.xirsys.com/getIceServers",
        data: {
            ident: "&lt; xyz &gt;",
            secret: "&lt; something-like-my-token &gt;",
            domain: "&lt; www.mydomain.com &gt;",
            application: "default",
            room: "default",
            secure: 1
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
            // data.d is where the iceServers object lives
            peerConnectionConfig = data.d;
            console.log(peerConnectionConfig);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I finally found that using **jQuery's $.ajax()** doesn't work as cool as **$.post()**, or simply I didn't get it.
Anyways here is my work-around with it.

The `function()` is a **success callback** in which the **STUN** and **TURN** servers are put in an array and used as was desired by the `RTCPeerConnection(server)` method.

```
$.post("https://api.xirsys.com/getIceServers", {
            ident: "your_username",
            secret: "XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XX",
            domain: "www.mydomainname.com",
            application: "default",
            room: "default",
            secure: 1
        },
        function (data, status) {
            console.log("Data: " + data + "nnStatus: " + status); //just for checking
            myResponse = data;
            turnServer = JSON.parse(myResponse);     //parsing to JSON because RTCPeerConnection() requires an object
            console.log(turnServer.d);    //d is the property that contains our STUN and TURN servers
            for (var i in turnServer.d.iceServers) {    //logic for STUN and TURN
                if(i == 0 ) {
                    STUN = turnServer.d.iceServers[i];
                    pc_config.iceServers.push(STUN);
                }
                if( i > 0 ) {
                    var turnUrl = turnServer.d.iceServers[i].url;
                    var turnSlice = turnUrl.slice(5,25);
                    TURN = {"url": "turn:" + turnServer.d.iceServers[i].username + '@' + turnSlice,
                        "credential" : turnServer.d.iceServers[i].credential }
                    pc_config.iceServers.push(TURN);

      }
```

Call RTCPeerConnection(pc_config) for fetching STUN and TURN servers, for productions otherwise it works fine on `localhost` with parameters set to `null`.